# sonar project version for dotnet application

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, msbuild-4.0, sonarqube-4.5

Sonar core version: 4.5.7

C# plugin version 5.2

SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild v2.0

We are using Sonarqube scanner for Msbuild in Jenkins to publish Sonarqube dashboards. For this setup, is there any way to automatically pass assembly version to sonar dashboard without hard-coding project version value in the Jenkins build configuration.

(in case of Java this value is picked automatically from pom files but for dotnet application this is a mandatory field under SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild –begin analysis step. Updating the value manually every time project version changes is the overhead we are trying to avoid

Comment: 4.5 was initially released in the fall of 2014. 5.6.6 is the current LTS version & you're not likely to get much help for versions before that.

Comment: @Coc Where would you expect the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild to read this information from? Projects within a solution might have an AssemblyInfo file, but a solution does not have such information, does it?

Comment: @Ann: since migration to sonar 5.x from 4.x comes with lots of restrictions in case of Dotnet applications (like dependency on VS 2015 in the build server, no support for MbUnit tests etc) we decided to stay with sonar 4.x for some more time. We have to study migration & its impacts before we make a final call

Comment: @Fabrice: I was wondering whether it can read from CommonAssemblyInfo file we have at solution level.